# How do I use Laravel's service container in a package (outside of an app)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a package, which can be consumed by Laravel applications. The package has a ServiceProvider, which consumers use when they want to instantiate stuff from the package.

Now, I would like to use this ServiceProvider in the package's own tests to resolve dependencies. Integration testing if you will.

How can I do that?

It looks like `resolve()` depends on `app()`, so am I correct in assuming that the Laravel service container is not standalone and can only be used inside of an application?

Answer (score 1):

**tldr; `composer require illuminate/container`**

The `App::` facade resolves to `Illuminate\Foundation\Application::class`, and the helper functions (including `app()`) are found in the same namespace. So you'd need to `composer require illuminate/foundation` to get this.

However, the actual container is at `Illuminate\Container\Container` - this is the base class which is extended by the `Application` class above, so you could get a thinned-down version of just the container with `composer require illuminate/container`.

I should also note that they appear to share the same `static::$instance` so using the illuminate container should work in both Laravel and non-Laravel apps.

**Example resolving an instance, and calling a method with automatic dependency injection:**

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

$container = Container::getInstance();
$concrete = $container->make(Some\Abstract\Interface::class);
$result = $container->call([$concrete, 'methodWithDependencies']);
```